# How to optimize the times of execute when to insert data with pdo?

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, pdo, insert

There is a huge two dimensional array which contain 500k sub one dimension arrays, every sub array contain 5 elements.
Now it is my job to insert all the data into a sqlite database.

```
function insert_data($array){
    Global $db;
    $dbh=new PDO("sqlite:{$db}");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO quote (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    foreach($array as $item){
        $query->execute(array_values($item));
            }
    $dbh=null;
        }
```

I want to optimize the data insert process that the execute action will be executed for 500k times,how to make it executed just one time?

Comment: what is your Storage Engine ? InnoDB or MyISAM ?

Comment: Using prepared statements like you are should be fairly efficient in this manner.  The question would be if PDO emulates with SQLite or not.  I don't think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to prevent running transactions for each insert, because it will be very slow indeed. So just start and commit the transaction, say for every 10k records.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $item) {
    $query->execute(array_values($item));
    if ($counter++ % 10000 == 0) {
        $dbh->commit();
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
    }
}
$dbh->commit();
```

Another solution, you can move an array in a csv file and then just import it.

Comment: Why are you adding transactions?

Comment: Because default auto-commit will do the same for each `execute`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php  "Auto-commit mode means that every query that you run has its own implicit transaction"

Comment: np :) I remember I worked with Postgres about a year ago and had a file with 10-11 millions records. It took me about 2 or 3 hours to import it. Once I applied this trick it was something about 5 or 6 minutes.

Comment: wonderful ,it is a magic trick , to insert 4 millions records , it cost only 4 minutes with your codes,it cost about  2  hours to do same job with my codes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a newer version of Sqlite (3.7.11+) then it supports batch inserts:

```
INSERT INTO quote (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5) VALUES
  (?,?,?,?,?),
  (?,?,?,?,?),
  (?,?,?,?,?);
```

You can use this to chunk your array into groups, and do batch inserts this way.
As pointed out by [Axalix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30270612/538216) you should also wrap the whole operation in a transaction.