# Mysql not inserting all rows after 900,000

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert randomly generated numbers into a mysql table.
When i insert 900,000 rows or under, everything is fine. But when I try to insert eg. 1,000,000 only 998,739 rows are inserted.
I have tried inserting 999,999 and it also inserts 998,739 rows. I have tried other numbers over 900,000 and none of them inserted the exact amount i wanted to.

I can't find any pattern in the amount of rows it is inserting (like x = x - 900)

If i insert eg. 10 rows after i inserted the 1,000,000 (998,739) rows, there is no problem.

I am inserting the rows like this:

```js
$i = 0;
$length = $_POST['length'];
while($i++ < $length){
    $key = rand(0, $length);
    $codes .= "('$key'), ";
}
    $codes = substr($codes, 0, -2);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO speedtest (Code) VALUES $codes";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);

?>
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Post your mysql table schema, and how you are inserting values. Show code.

Comment: @Muhammed I added the code i am using to insert the rows

Comment: Post table schema please `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Comment: You have this issue because of the "max_allowed_packet" limit exceeded problem. You shouldn't insert records in the DB this way. Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270385/how-to-optimize-the-times-of-execute-when-to-insert-data-with-pdo/30270612

Comment: If you're running this from a browser, check to make sure your script doesn't timeout. Insert the occasional sleep() to verify that this is a timeout issue.

Comment: @MuhammedM. CREATE TABLE `speedtest` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Code` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: @Axalix How would you suggest i do it?

Comment: I would suggest you to use php PDO and this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30270612/4621324

Comment: mysql INT is defined, although you didn't specify `unsigned`, it will still be able to hold more than 1mil autoincrement ids. So problem is with your settings, mysql or PHP. Does your PHP script end normally? no timeout or anything weird? How long this script runs? You could also try `bindParam` with `PDO`, you could simply run a for loop for as many times as you want.

Comment: @Axalix Learned something from the linked approach, had to upvote it.